# guardar una variable o multiples dentro de una variable php

Tags: php, mysql

envío estos datos por POST
`hasta #producto_15` si hago `#producto_16` ya no guarda en mi bd por la estructura que tiene.

```html
<div id="producto_1" class="row form-group productoss">
<input type='text' name='nombreprod1' placeholder='Nombre del producto'>
<input type='text' name='skuprod1' placeholder='Sku' required>
<input type='number' name='cantprod1' placeholder='Cantidad' >
<input type='number' name='cosprod1' placeholder='Costo' >
</div>
<div id="producto_2" class="row form-group productoss">
<input type='text' name='nombreprod2' placeholder='Nombre del producto' >
<input type='text' name='skuprod2' placeholder='Sku' required>
<input type='number' name='cantprod2' placeholder='Cantidad' >
<input type='number' name='cosprod2' name='cosprod' placeholder='Costo' >
</div>
...
```

Y los proceso en un PHP

```
$pro1 = $_POST['nombreprod'];
$pro2 = $_POST['nombreprod2'];
$pro3 = $_POST['nombreprod3'];
$pro4 = $_POST['nombreprod4'];
$pro5 = $_POST['nombreprod5'];
$pro6 = $_POST['nombreprod6'];
...
```

Quiero comprobar si existen cada uno y si existen guardarlos dentro de una variable, delimitarlo y que guardare en una base de datos.
Algo así:

```
$nomproductos = $pro1.$pro2....$pro50
```

Me recomendaron ponerlo todo en una variable para guardarlo en una columna llamada "product" ya que por ahora estoy guardando en varias columnas (y solo puedo añadir 15 productos)lo estaba haciendo así hasta ahora:

```
INSERT INTO productos (sku01, sku02, sku03, sku04, sku05, sku06,
    sku07, sku08, sku09, sku10, sku11, sku12, sku13, sku14, sku15, pro01, pro02, pro03, pro04, pro05, pro06, pro07,
    pro08, pro09, pro10, pro11, pro12, pro13, pro14, pro15, cap01, cap02, cap03, cap04, cap05, cap06, cap07, cap08,
    cap09, cap10, cap11, cap12, cap13, cap14, cap15, cxp01, cxp02, cxp03, cxp04, cxp05, cxp06, cxp07, cxp08, cxp09,
    cxp10, cxp11, cxp12, cxp13, cxp14, cxp15, cop01, cop02, cop03, cop04, cop05, cop06, cop07, cop08, cop09, cop10,
    cop11, cop12, cop13, cop14, cop15, subto) VALUES
    ('$sk1', '$sku2', '$sku3', '$sku4', '$sku5', '$sku6', '$sku7', '$sku8', '$sku9', '$sku10',
        '$sku11', '$sku12', '$sku13', '$sku14', '$sku15', '$pro1', '$pro2', '$pro3', '$pro4', '$pro5', '$pro6',
        '$pro7', '$pro8', '$pro9', '$pro10', '$pro11', '$pro12', '$pro13', '$pro14', '$pro15', '$cap1', '$cap2',
        '$cap3', '$cap4', '$cap5', '$cap6', '$cap7', '$cap8', '$cap09', '$cap10', '$cap11', '$cap12', '$cap13',
        '$cap14', '$cap15', '$cxp1', '$cxp2', '$cxp3', '$cxp4', '$cxp5', '$cxp6', '$cxp7', '$cxp8', '$cxp9',
        '$cxp10', '$cxp11', '$cxp12', '$cxp13', '$cxp14', '$cxp15', '$cop1', '$cop2', '$cop3', '$cop4', '$cop5',
        '$cop6', '$cop7', '$cop8', '$cop9', '$cop10', '$cop11', '$cop12', '$cop13', '$cop14', '$cop15')
```

como podrán ver era una buena opcion hasta listas de 15 productos. Si no me hubiese matado horas en san google no les vendría a molestar la vida, llevo 2 meses aprendiendo php, agradecezco su respuesta.

Comment: No entiendo porque quieres guardar todos los productos en una misma fila.  Porque mejor no cambias la estructura de tu tabla para que tenga solo 4 columnas y asi puedes guardar todos los productos que quieras?

Comment: debiera ser al revés la estructura de la tabla

Comment: tendras que hacer una modificacion de tu tabla, porque asi como tienes eso no es nada practico, la otra opcion seria convertir todo el $_POST en un json purgango aquello que llegue vacio, pero el comentario de alanfcm es ideal.

Comment: eso es exactamente lo que quiero hacer, guardar todos los productos que quiero, lo que muestro al final es como esta ahora, pero quiero que sea de la forma mas lógica, en el final del post lo explico `era una buena opcion`

Comment: Como información adicional, te recomiendo que busques información sobre **Normalización de Bases de Datos**. Aclara bastantes dudas sobre la estructura de la misma.